# diskpart shows one partition as two different ones

Tags: windows, mbr, gpt, diskpart, disk-management

I want to convert my hard disk from MBR to GPT via `mbr2gpt`, but for it to work, I can have a maximum of three primary partitions and `diskpart` is labeling the same partition as two separate partitions [extended and logical]; how can I fix this?

- While I only have four partitions, `diskpart` shows five: [image: DiskPart]
- Disk Management shows only four partitions: [image: Disk Management]

Comment: You will have to delete that extended partition to use MBR2GPT. Since it’s unused your likely to simply delete it. Before you do this you might want to verify your system is actually compatible with Windows 11. You will want to do the conversion to GPT the create the unused data partition

Comment: How does Windows 11 compatibility come in this? I'm confused. Also, I checked and my PC is not compatible

Comment: Why are you attempting to use GPT? My advice still applies, delete the extended partition and convert to GPT, or use a third-party tool that doesn’t have the same restrictions

Comment: I want to access UEFI and at the moment my BIOS is in Legacy. I want to access UEFI Firmware Settings to turn on Hardware Virtualization to run virtual machine. I'll see if I can delete the extended partition. Thank You!

Comment: You don’t have to enable UEFI to enable Hardware Virtualization. Your attempting to make an unnecessary change to your system, in order to enable hardware virtualization, what makes you think UEFI is required for AMD-V/VT-x?

Comment: @Ramhound True, but running CSM mode is inefficient and results in a quantifiable loss of performance. CSM Mode should never be used on any machine after 2017.

Comment: @VirenJoshi Unsure why you have [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) enabled in UEFI _(it's disabled by default)_ - CSM Mode should _never_ be used after 2017, as its _sole purpose_ was to support distros that didn't support EFI boot circa <2017 _(Win ≥7 supports EFI boot)_. It would be wonderful if folks spread the message about CSM Mode, as it should _never_ be enabled and should be completely ignored since enabling CSM mode results in a quantifiable loss in performance, requiring UEFI to emulate BIOS' 16bit arch within a 32bit env.

Answer (score 5):

You have an extended partition, which is a mechanism for avoiding the
maximum partition number of MBR, which is `4`.

The documentation of
[mbr2gpt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt)
includes this:

> **Disk Prerequisites**
>
> Before any change to the disk is made, MBR2GPT validates the layout
> and geometry of the selected disk to ensure that:
>
> - The disk is currently using MBR
> - There is enough space not occupied by partitions to store the primary and secondary GPTs:
>
>   - 16KB + 2 sectors at the front of the disk
>   - 16KB + 1 sector at the end of the disk
> - **There are at most 3 primary partitions in the MBR partition table**
> - One of the partitions is set as active and is the system partition
> - **The disk does not have any extended/logical partition**
> - The BCD store on the system partition contains a default OS entry pointing to an OS partition
> - The volume IDs can be retrieved for each volume which has a drive letter assigned
> - All partitions on the disk are of MBR types recognized by Windows or has a mapping specified using the /map command-line option

**Conclusion**: Your disk as-is cannot be converted to GPT.
You will need to delete the extended partition,
after saving all data.

Comment: _"Why do you want to convert?"_: OP needs to switch to GPT in order to disable [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) in UEFI _(unsure how OP came to have CSM Mode enabled, as it should never be enabled since its sole purpose was to support distros that didn't support EFI boot circa <2017 (Win ≥7 supports EFI boot); enabling CSM Mode results in a quantifiable loss in performance, requiring UEFI to emulate BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment)_.

Comment: @JW0914, some of us have computers that are more than four years old.

Comment: @Mark You misunderstood - CSM Mode was only relevant until 2017, as all distros gained EFI boot by 2017; there is no practical or fundamental reason for enabling CSM Mode post-2017 since it literally serves no purpose beyond booting to a legacy peripheral's option ROM. The only reason this is still an issue is due to parroted misinformation from folks [in general] not taking the 30s to google [_CSM \[Legacy\] Mode_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) to understand what it actually is, what it does, and why no one should have it enabled.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to convert my hard disk from MBR to GTP and hence I'm using mbr2gpt tool. But, for it to work I can have maximum 4 partitions (max. 3 primary). I actually have only 4 partitions but diskpart is shows that I have 5. It is labeling the same partition as two separate partitions (extended and logical).

This is normal. It's how logical partitions *work*, and it's how they bypass the "4 partition" limit in MBR – all of them actually exist *inside* the "extended" partition.

Normally the extended super-partition is not included in the partition count by most tools, but technically it still occupies a "primary" slot in the MBR.

So it seems to me that your disk actually satisfies the "maximum 4 partitions (max. 3 primary)" requirement... but that depends on whether mbr2gpt counts the extended partition as primary or not.

(It also seems to me that the requirement is a bit odd – maybe mbr2gpt is doing things a little backwards and trying to create EFI partitions before doing the actual MBR-to-GPT translation? You could actually bypass this by doing the conversion by hand using gdisk & bcdboot, like it was done for years before mbr2gpt.exe was added to Windows.)

> Here's a snip of my Disk Management, which shows that I actually only have 4 partitions.

The dark green border you have around E: is actually the "Extended partition" indicator. It accurately represents that the "extended" partition reserves the entire remaining disk area that'll be used by logical partitions.

Comment: MBR2GPT requirements are simple, there can only be 3 partitions (basically), in order to use it.  The author has 3 plus an extended partition.  One of the other requirements is not to have any extended partitions, look to the primary rule of only having 3 partitions, on the reason why that's the case.